# Application crashing after calling a method

Tags: c++, qt, oop, pointers, memory

I want to return a `QString` value from a function that exists in class called `DB` in my `MainWindow` class, but it always crashes the application.

**db.h**

```
#ifndef DB_H
#define DB_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSQl>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDialog>

class DB : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DB(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QString getDriver() const;
    void setDriver(const QString &value);

private:
    QString Driver="test";

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // DB_H
```

and this is **db.cpp**

```
#include "db.h"

DB::DB(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{

}

QString DB::getDriver() const
{
    return Driver;
}


void DB::setDriver(const QString &value)
{
    Driver = value;
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QObject>
#include "Db.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    DB *conn;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString driverfromdb = conn->getDriver();
    qDebug() << driverfromdb;
}
```

And this what happen when I click the pushbutton: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzx3L.png)

Comment: Are you assigning `conn`? I can't find any assignment in the code you posted.

Comment: @Farini thanks for information i did change tags :) sorry ^^

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann i created conn from Db so i can call functions !!

Comment: For crashes, you need to include the stack trace in the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `conn` is an uninitialized pointer. Nowhere in this code do you actually create an instance of `DB`.

Comment: thanks @IgorTandetnik it's solved i have just to create an instance
`conn = new DB;`
befor using
`conn->getDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a pointer to `DB` class inside your `MainWindow` class

```
DB *conn;
```

but you never initialize it. At the moment it does not point to anything, so if you try to access it:

```
QString driverfromdb = conn->getDriver(); // boom, conn is somewhere in the void
```

The solution is simple, you need to create a DB object before using it, e.g.:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    conn = new DB();
    QString driverfromdb = conn->getDriver();
    qDebug() << driverfromdb;
}
```

or just let `conn` be a typical variable, not an pointer:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    DB conn; // conn is created after creating MainWindow object
```

This way you have not to initialize anything and you will avoid crashes.

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), conn(new DB),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete conn;
    delete ui;
}
```